# How to extract expression names using face-api.js?

Tags: reactjs, face-detection, face-api

Currently when I console log on the following code: ([API Github](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js))
For the face expression detection I have the following line of code:

```
const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(videoRef.current, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
```

When I console log the detections variable it gives the following result:

```
Array(1)0: alignedRect: FaceDetection {_imageDims: Dimensions, _score: 0.8277419589060608,_classScore: 0.8277419589060608, _className: "", _box: Box}detection: FaceDetection {_imageDims: Dimensions, _score: 0.8277419589060608, _classScore: 0.8277419589060608,_className: "", _box: Box}expressions: FaceExpressions {neutral: 0.9946907162666321, happy: 0.005221708677709103, sad: 0.000022168851501191966, angry: 0.000003129790229650098, fearful:1.3060009962373442e-7, …}landmarks: FaceLandmarks68 {_imgDims: Dimensions, _shift: Point,_positions: Array(68)}unshiftedLandmarks: FaceLandmarks68 {_imgDims: Dimensions, _shift: Point, _positions: Array(68)}__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

Now I want to use the expressions and apply a max function on the values against each expression name. But I cannot access it. How can I access this expressions to use further?

```
expressions: FaceExpressions {neutral: 0.9946907162666321, happy: 0.005221708677709103, sad: 0.000022168851501191966, angry: 0.000003129790229650098, fearful: 1.3060009962373442e-7, …}
```

Comment: You could iterate over the keys of your object to then get the max of their values.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result like this

```
const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(videoRef.current, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
if (detections ) {
      const dims = faceapi.matchDimensions(CANVAS_DISPLAY, OGVIDEO, true)
      const resizedResult = faceapi.resizeResults(detections , dims)
      const minConfidence = 0.6
      let finalResult = Object.values(detections.expressions)// this is the expressions 
}
```